# HTA application, using ".htc" file. Need to catch HTML-css change event

Tags: internet-explorer, hta

I'm developing HTA application that need IE as working eviroment. And IE has ".HTC" file to teach the HTML tags the way to "behave".

OK, everything works fine until I need to catch the event when the HTML tag's css changes. I'm using the method of timer, but I wonder if there's any better way ? (using JavaScript is OK if necessary) Thanks all suggestions!

Comment: Maybe you could use `propertychange` event on `body` for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Teemu! Using propertychange was the correct solution. But instead of apply this property to body, I must apply it to *every tag* I need to watch.

I can do it by JS. Thanks again!

```
<div onpropertychange="alert('changed!')"> </div>
```

Note : This method won't let you know if the tag's innerHTML changed, only alert if the tag's attribute & css changed. Besides, when the tag is set to "disabled", no event will fire when the tag's css change.

Full references about onpropertychange of IE could be found here : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536956